# sorting multidimensional lists in python

Tags: python, sorting

```
a = ["1", "11.1", "1.11.1", ".1", "2", "2.2", "2.1.9", "2.2.1", "1.2", "1.01.1"]
b = []

for x in a:
    y = x.split(".")
    b.append(y)
    
j = sorted(b)

for jj in j:
    print (jj)
```

Results in:

```
['', '1']
['1']
['1', '01', '1']
['1', '11', '1']
['1', '2']
['11', '1']
['2']
['2', '1', '9']
['2', '2']
['2', '2', '1']
```

The desired output should be:

```
['', '1']
['1']
['1', '01', '1']
['1', '11', '1']
['1', '2']
['2']
['2', '1', '9']
['2', '2']
['2', '2', '1']
['11', '1']
```

The problem with the first output is 11 is not greater than 2, so the list is out of order.
The correct or desired order is the second output.

I cant tell if the solution would require putting a 0 before the the other numbers somehow.

Comment: Those are strings.  `"11"` is less than `"2"`.

Comment: Do you really want to split those strings into lists, or is that just part of your attempt to sort them?

Comment: Is that empty string neccessary in the output?

Comment: @IshanShishodiya What's the alternative?

Comment: You'll just need to define a `key` function that orders things the way you want. E.g. if the string is all digits, you may wish to convert to integer. Looks like you'll want empty string to convert to `0`.

Comment: @If that empty string ain't necessary in the output then, we can convert the whole data into float and sort it on that basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason appears to be as the data is in string format. To sort it the way you are looking for, convert each element to int and then sort. You can get this by updating the code like this...

```
def to_int(val):
    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
    
a = ["1", "11.1", "1.11.1", ".1", "2", "2.2", "2.1.9", "2.2.1", "1.2", "1.01.1"]
b = []

for x in a:
    y = x.split(".")
    y = [to_int(x) for x in y]
    b.append(y)
    
j = sorted(b)

for jj in j:
    print (jj)
```